# How to set environment variables when executing a scenario with maven?

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I have a gatling project where I make use of environment variables:

```scala
val Feeder: String = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("FEEDER", "sts")
```

When I run it using maven I try to set the value of that variable, but I always get the default value:

```sh
$ mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=simulations.MySimulation -DFEEDER=something
```

I've also tried to just set the value in the terminal before executing maven:

```
$ FEEDER=something

$ mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=simulations.MySimulation
```

but I always get the default value "sts"

Am I missing something? How can I set the value I want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing env variables and Java System Properties.

`scala.util.Properties.envOrElse` is for the former while `-DFEEDER=something` is for the latter.

Please use `scala.util.Properties.propOrElse` or `sys.props.getOrElse`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with `export FEEDER=something` and it worked... it seems setting the value in the current terminal is not enough with Maven

Comment: -Dfoo=bar sets a Java System property. It has nothing to do with env var.

Comment: @PabloLozano `export FEEDER=something` sets this environment variable in "current terminal" only and it will be enough for "maven" (actually the way you are trying to read it, has nothing to do with maven and is same for any Java, Scala or even Kotlin application). Environment Variables and Java system properties are two very different things. `-Dsomeproperty=somevalue` sets java system property and not environment vaiable. `scala.util.Properties.envOrElse` is used for Environment Vaiables; `scala.util.Properties.propOrElse` is used for java system properties.

Comment: You can also use `java.lang.System.getenv(envVarName)` and `java.lang.System.getProperty(propertyName)` for same.